# JPA - Cannot delete row due to foreign key constraint

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa, eclipselink

I am using JPA2 (EclipseLink) and my entity objects look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Dashboard
{
    @Id
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="dashboard", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<LogResult> logResults;

    //getter-setters
}

@Entity
public class LogResult
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long id;

    private Dashboard dashboard;

    //getter-setters
}
```

and I have code like this to delete a dashboard:

```
EntityManager em = PersistenceInitializer.newEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.remove(dashboard);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

However when I execute the code above, I get an error msg regarding a foreign key constraint on the logresult table.

Why is this so? Doesn't using CascadeType.ALL mean all that should be handled for me?

**Update** here is the actual error output on the console

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`crs`.`logresult`, CONSTRAINT `FK_LOGRESULT_DASHBOARD_NAME` FOREIGN KEY (`DASHBOARD_NAME`) REFERENCES `dashboard` (`NAME`))
Error Code: 1451
```

Comment: Any other table has relationship with LogResult table?

Comment: is the relationship bi-directional ? does LogResult have a @ManyToOne getDashboard()?

Comment: @radai: No. LogResult has no annotation on the 'dashboard' field.

Comment: @Stanley no. only dashboard.

Comment: Do you have many-to-one relationship on the `LogResult` side? There is no annotation in the presented code. Is it present in `orm.xml`?

Comment: Have you maintained both sides of the bidirectional relationship?  Remove can only cascade over logResults that dashboard references.   If that's not the case, turn logging on and remove the constraint if possible to see all the SQL for the transaction since it might help show what is going wrong

Comment: @pdeva if the relationship is not bi-directional then LogResult should not even contain a dashboard field. If it should contain it then you have modeled a bi-directional relationship and you should annotate things as such

Comment: I have exactly the same problem here. also using mysql

Answer (score 0):

For EclipseLink implementation, see the EclispeLink JPA Extensions guide: http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/toc.htm

Comment: For real now...Simply posting a link big fat web page (didn't even bother to give a specific location on it) is definitely not an answer that is of good quality on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Explicitly add `cascade = CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN` as well. When parent entity is deleted first, all the child objects become orphan. `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN` cascade type makes JPA to remove those orphan objects.

e.g. below:

```
   @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
```

Comment: @Vikdor: I was updating the answer already. Check the updated answer.

Comment: cool, thanks! Is this something specific to JPA2 / EclipseLink?

Comment: there is no CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN in jpa. I am already using "orphanRemoval = true" in the annotation, as shown in the original question

Comment: `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN` is Hibernate proprietary solution. OP is using EclipseLink.